# Activiti LDAP integration

Tags: ldap, activiti

I've managed to configure connection to LDAP under activiti-standalone-context.xml

```
<property name="configurators">
          <list>
              <bean class="org.activiti.ldap.LDAPConfigurator">

                <!-- Server connection params -->
                <property name="server" value="ldap://10.0.1.35" />
                <property name="port" value="389" />
                <property name="user" value="CN=Activiti,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM" />
                <property name="password" value="pass" />

                <!-- Query params -->
                <property name="baseDn" value="DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM" />
                <property name="queryUserByUserId" value="(&amp;(objectclass=user)( sAMAccountName ={0})" />
                <property name="queryUserByFullNameLike" value="(&amp;(objectclass=user) (|({0}=*{1}*)({2}=*{3}*)))" />
                <property name="queryGroupsForUser" value="(&amp;(objectclass=group) (uniqueMember={0}))" />

                <!-- Attribute config -->
                <property name="userIdAttribute" value="sAMAccountName" />
                <property name="userFirstNameAttribute" value="cn" />
                <property name="userLastNameAttribute" value="sn" />

                <property name="groupIdAttribute" value="cn" />
                <property name="groupNameAttribute" value="cn" />

              </bean>
          </list>
        </property>
```

Under ui-context

```
  <list>
    <value>admin</value>
  </list>
  </property>
  <property name="userGroups">
    <list>
      <value>user</value>
    </list>
```

However when trying to login using domain user: invalid user or password

In logs there are no errors,

Thanks

Comment: Verify that the username and password are correct by authenticating a connection to the directory server using a known good tool like `ldapsearch`. Then match the configuration against the credentials used in the `ldapsearch` test. View the LDAP server logs where the operations occur and learn the LDAP Servers' viewpoint of the request-response cycle. These are basic troubleshooting techniques used to establish a grounding when troubleshooting LDAP clients.

Comment: which version of activiti you are using??

Answer (score 2):

Check log 
if it relevant to this **property**.

```
< property name="baseDn" value="DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM" / >
```

if true - check the value of baseDn by add more information such as:

```
< property name="baseDn" value="ou=your_own_ou,dc=domain,dc=com" / >
```

remember that **CAP Chars** are used here.